# Does Django's Field.unique creates a primary key?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Does Django's Field.unique creates a primary key. If not it will de normalize a table where it is declared?

Comment: It simply creates a unique index for that column. Primary keys must be unique but not all unique columns are primary keys. What is your question, exactly?

Comment: I guess that makes sense, it creates an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This property just verify if the entering value exists in the db, if exists it will trigger an error.

For example you can use `unique=True` in your `EmailField` if you don't want to have duplicate emails.

You can see the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#unique).

Regards.